# Find value of variable for unique, infinite and no solutions in equation system

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

How do i find which values of a variable in a equations system that gives unique, infinite and no solutions?

My example:

\begin{align*}
    ax + y + az &= 2 \\
    x + ay + z &= 2 \\
    x + az &= 1
\end{align*}

"Find the values of a for which the system has no solutions, exactly one solution, or infinitely many solutions."

I used the `Solve` line below to find unique solutions:

```
Solve[a*x + y + a*z == 2 && x + a*y + z == 2 && x + a*z == 1, {a, x, y, z}]
```

But after searching forums and Mathematica documentations for hours i still can't find any examples of how to find the others.

Solved:
Using

```
Solve[Det[{{a, 1, a}, {1, a, 1}, {1, 0, a}}] == 0, a]
```

I got values for which the coefficient matrix is singular. In my case it return -1 and 1.
Using these values for a in my original system answered my question. In my case a = 1 return infinite solutions (with a loose x and z) and -1 had no solutions.

Comment: What does `Solve[Det[{{a, 1, a}, {1, a, 1}, {1, 0, a}}] == 0, a]` give?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what it means right away, but it gives me
{{a -> -1}, {a -> 1}, {a -> 1}}

Comment: Okay. So, if you replace `a` in your original system with any of those numbers, and then try using `Solve[]`, what happens?

Comment: Running
Solve[x + y + z == 2 && x + y + z == 2 && x + z == 1, { x, y, z}]
Ergo a = 1
gives me 
{{y -> 1, z -> 1 - x}}

Comment: ...and that's your "infinitely many solutions" case, since you can set `x` to any value, no? How about the other value of `a` you got?

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help!
I see now that my original Solve line gave me {a -> 1, x -> 1 - z, y -> 1}, which is exactly what i got from your lines.. I guess i had the answer right in front of me the entire time; i never realized x and z was loose.

Care to explain what the Solve[Det[{{a, 1, a}, {1, a, 1}, {1, 0, a}}] == 0, a] line does and how you got it?
Cheers!

Comment: Have matrices and determinants been covered in your class already? That line just finds the values for which the coefficient matrix is singular.

Comment: Also, let me encourage you to write an answer to your own question if you believe you have figured out the answer already.

Comment: By "answering your own question", I did not mean for you to edit your question with the answer. Use the answer box below. ;)

Comment: side note: you may want to fix the example at the top of your question : for Mathematica `az`  and `a*z` are 2 different things

Comment: Ah yes, i used ctrl + k to format the example to look a bit better even though it's not code, but you are right that is confusing.